# How to prevent SQL Server Management Studio from changing text to uppercase

Tags: sql-server, ssms

SQL Server Management Studio (v18.7.1) is changing SQL statements from lowercase to uppercase in the editor.

How to disable text transformation?

Comment: AFAIK there is no native function like that in SSMS, it has nothing resembling smart formatting of T-SQL (if only it did). The closest thing it has to this is presenting native functions in IntelliSense as uppercase by default, but that will not override anything you type yourself. If it's IntelliSense you're concerned with, you can change that to a lowercase default in the options ("casing for built-in function names"). If not, you'll have to be more specific about what you observe.